# What is the second argument in QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString?

Tags: pyqgis

In QGIS 3 I am trying to get a layer in the Python Console. And I have to put to arguments in the function `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()`. The first argument is self-explanatory, the string. But I don't understand what the second argument is (the `QgsProject`).

Could someone clarify me what that second argument is?

Comment: The second argument is the context. Try QgsProject.instance().

Answer (score 2):

The second argument in [`QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingUtils.html#ad67cf1a2d63da7917c0a2f00d9abc15b) refers to context i.e. [`QgsProcessingContext`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingContext.html) e.g. information that wraps your `QgsProject`.

> Interprets a string as a map layer within the supplied context.
>
> The method will attempt to load a layer matching the passed string.
> E.g. if the string matches a layer ID or name within the context's
> project or temporary layer store then this layer will be returned. If
> the string is a file path and `allowLoadingNewLayers` is `true`, then the
> layer at this file path will be loaded and added to the context's
> temporary layer store. Ownership of the layer remains with the context
> or the context's current project.
>
> The typeHint can be used to dictate the type of map layer expected.

More details can be found in this thread: [What does context mean in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419632/what-does-context-mean-in-pyqgis)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to access the layers.
As @christoph tells you, it is easier and more direct to use the methods of `QgsProject`.

We start by instantiating `pry=QgsProject.instance()`

1.- **To access a layer by its name you can use**

```
pry.mapLayersByName()
```

It returns a list, because you can have several layers with the same name. If only one layer matches, you can access it by its index:

```
pry.mapLayersByName("transport")[0]
```

2.- From QGIS3.10 you also have the `mapLayersByShortName()` method

3.- If you want a list with all the layers:

```
pry.mapLayers()
```

Returns a dictionary, the layer id is the key

On the other hand, you can combine with the methods of iface (QgisInterface) and QgsMapCanvas

**1.- Get the active layer****:

- `iface.activeLayer()` returns the active layer
- `iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()` generates the same result

**2.- A list of the layers visible on the canvas**

```
iface.mapCanvas().layers()
```

Comment: All is true but not answering the question.