# What does context mean in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, terminology

When writing PyQGIS scripts, especially processing script and expression function, I come across the term **context**. I use it, but I don't know what all contexts mean actually.

There are also `Qgs***Context` classes. For example,
[QgsExpressionContext](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContext.html), [QgsSymbolWidgetContext](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbolWidgetContext.html), [QgsProcessingContext](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometryCheckContext.html),
[QgsAttributeEditorContext](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeEditorContext.html), ... .

What does `context` refer in all those class names and in some methods in PyQGIS?

Comment: This question is different from [What are parameters and context in PyQGIS processAlgorithm function?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/386933/29431). The other is about how to define our own `context` variable.

Comment: In basic software engineering, "context" is used to connote ancillary information needed to generate results, usually dynamic, and associated with processing or the state of processing. It is especially used in interfaces where a developer provides a user function, as custom data to be provided to the custom function to maintain state information on the progress of execution. There's usually a setter for a function in the form of `setFunction(int (*fn)(void *data, void *context), void *context)` (where `data` is something to be processed (a row or object), and `context` is user-provided).

Comment: see this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145091/the-term-context-in-programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to explain as far as I know what `context` means.

> Context can be seen as a bucket to pass information around.([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145178/5569709))

Let's say you write a function (`funcA`) which calls another function (`funcB`) and passes multiple arguments. And `funcB` calls a `funcC`, and passes additional arguments with argument taken from `funcA`.

```
def funcA ():
       
    param1 = "value1"
    param2 = "value2"
    ...
    param10 = "value10"
    
    funcB(param1, param2, ... ,param10)


def funcB(param1, param2, ... param10):

    param11 = "value11"
    ...
    param20 = "value20"

    funcC("ANY_VALUE", param1, ..., param10, param11, ... param20) 


def funcC(PARAM, param1, param2, ..., param20):

    # use PARAM
    # use other parameters if needed.
```

In that case, `funcC` access all information about the environment by means of `funcA` and `funcB`. As you imagine, passing multiple arguments is not a preferable way. So developers wrap all information, which `funcC` may need, into one container. That container can be a `key:value`  pairs (dictionary in Python), a class, or another thing.

Let's look at how we pass parameters using a dictionary or a class.

**Using dictionary**:

```
def funcA ():
       
    dictionary = {"param1": "value1", ..., "param10": "value10"}
    
    funcB(dictionary)


def funcB(dictionary):

    new_dictionary = {"param11": "value11", ..., "param20": "value20"}
    dictionary.update(new_dictionary)

    funcC("ANY_VALUE", dictionary) 


def funcC(PARAM, dictionary):

    #
    #
```

**Using class**:

```
class Information():
    pass


def funcA ():
       
    information = Information()
    information.param1 = "value1"
    ...
    information.param10 = "value10"
    
    funcB(information)


def funcB(information):

    information.param11 = "value11"
    ...
    information.param20 = "value20"

    funcC("ANY_VALUE", information) 


def funcC(PARAM, information):

    #
    #
```

You see? You send all information as a bucket to `funcC`. So, what is the context here? Well! `information` and `dictionary` have the same duty as context, which is passing information.

Now let's get to PyQGIS part.

Define a function in Expression Function Editor:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def my_func(feature, parent, context):
    print(context)
```

and call `my_func` in Expression window. You will get a [`QgsExpressionContext`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContext.html) reference. This `context` variable provides you information related to the Expression environment.

[image]

Then make a new processing script (Processing Toolbox > Script button > Create New Script from Template), and define `processAlgorithm` as follows and run:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    
    print(context)
    
    return {}
```

It prints the reference of a [QgsProcessingContext](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingContext.html) instance. That means, this `context` provides you all information related to the Processing environment, which you may need while scripting a processing algorithm.

[image]

In a nutshell, if you see a `context` variable, it is fantastic. You should be glad that you can easily access information about the environment. Otherwise, you would have to write the relevant code yourself when you needed that information.